# How do I get the code for the locked door at the bottom of the Brain Scorcher?

Tags: stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl

In S.T.A.L.K.E.R.: Shadow of Chernobyl, when you go into the *Red Forest* to turn off the *Brain Scorcher*, you descend into a secret laboratory, which is known as *X-19*.

When you're at the bottom and have turned off the Scorcher, before you trace your steps back up, there is a locked code door. Does anybody know if that door can be opened, what's behind it and where to get the code from?
To help your memories, next to it are also two... let's call them cooling towers. Both having a ladder that leads down to spiral stairs. One of them containing Burner anomalies, the other is just blocked.

[image: screenshot of the locked code door on the left]

The door can be seen on the left side of the screenshot. Up on that scaffolding on the right is the button that you press to turn off the Scorcher.

There is a second code door higher up with the code 342089 (which you get from the "Monolith soldier's PDA") that contains some supplies. That is **not** the one I am talking about. The code does **not** work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can´t open the door. You can do it with the "gun trick", but there is nothing inside. Only a square room the size of the door.

Comment: How anticlimactic. :) What's the 'gun trick', btw.?

Comment: @Cort I think it's an old glitch noticed throughout the series in which your drop your gun through the door collision and the game will debate which to move to fix the collision, and most stupidly chooses the door instead. You can see demonstration in [this speedrun](https://youtu.be/O_kx7U-4ptQ?t=740).

Answer (score 4):

Found on the [internet](http://www.gamespot.com/pc/action/stalker/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-44578470&pid=540331):

> Door behind sniper and on road to Brain Scorcher=1287975, 2nd door inside Brain Scorcher building=342089, unknown door (I still haven't found it)=19840519

Comment: I don't have it installed right now, so I can't confirm. Good find though. Any idea how you're supposed to get this code in-game? Mind sharing your source?

Comment: Sorry forgot to post the source link:
http://www.gamespot.com/pc/action/stalker/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-44578470&pid=540331

And i don't have any clue where to get the code in-game (If it's even possible).

Comment: Chances are, the user jailbreaked the files to get the codes.